# What application layer is responsible for providing external service integration capabilities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have a Spring Boot web application with presentation, business logic, data access logical tiers. Is it conceptually correct to describe external interface calls (REST, WS) to be in the Data Access Layer? I.e. also where database access resides. Conceptually, it would make sense to me.

Also, should interaction with external services be called DAOs or "clients"? I think e.g. Spring Boot tutorials call RestTemplates to be REST "clients", so one possibility would be to have a DAO, which then uses the RestTemplate "client" to actually make the REST call. Would this make sense?

Comment: I think, that Controller (REST or WS) is more like business-logic tire. You can replace one database layer with another, but business-logic should not change. Also, you can change view engine, but it should not affect the business-logic or data tier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it conceptually correct to describe external interface calls (REST,
>   WS) to be in the Data Access Layer

Data Access Object is used to abstract and encapsulate access to the data source. Data source could be a persistent store, external service, repository and etc.

> one possibility would be to have a DAO, which then uses the RestTemplate "client" to actually make the REST call

DAO implements the access mechanism required to work with the data source. It is responsibility of DAO to provide abstract API for application, but implementation can be any. Using `RestTemplate` to make REST calls in DAO is perfectly fine.

Article "[Core J2EE Patterns - Data Access Object](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)" might be useful for reading

Comment: Good explanation. As a side note, this would mean that both database access and external system access are behind a DAO layer. However, e.g. Spring (Boot) often defines three layers. Controller, Service, Repository. But this would almost drive it in the direction that you have Controller, Service, DAO (and DAO can contain Repository)